# How to get the expected output shape from a unet model?

Tags: python, image-segmentation

I have an image segmentation task where my input image shape is (140, 85, 95, 4) and the output label shape is (140, 85, 95). Below is my model:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, Input, Rescaling

num_classes = 4

my_model = tf.keras.Sequential([

Input(shape = (85, 95, 4), name = 'image'),
Rescaling(scale = 1./255),
Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),

Conv2DTranspose(filters = 256, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
Conv2DTranspose(filters = 256, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
Conv2DTranspose(filters = 128, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
Conv2DTranspose(filters = 128, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
Conv2DTranspose(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),
Conv2DTranspose(filters = 64, kernel_size = 3, strides = 1, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same'),

Conv2D(filters = num_classes, kernel_size = 3, activation = 'softmax', padding = 'same')

])
```

After training, I tried predicting one image and the model produced a label with shape (140, 85, 95, 4) as the output but I want it to be (140, 85, 95) or (140, 85, 95, 1).

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your last layer uses 4 filter because `num_classes` is set to 4, resulting in an array with 4 channels in the last dimension. If you simply want only one channel simply change the number of filters for the last convolutional layer to one (`filters=1`).

Comment: I tried setting  the last "filters" to 1 but it resulted in another error: `labels.shape` must equal `logits.shape` except for the last dimension. Received: labels.shape=(1130500,) and logits.shape=(11900, 95)

Comment: That has to do with the shape of the labels and the output from your model. Make sure that both contain the same number of observations.

Comment: The number of observations are the same (140). Do you think it's because of the image shape, each one has a shape of (85, 95, 4) whereas a normal image's shape is (x, y, 3)? What else can I try?

Comment: It seems that it simply a shape error since 1130500 is equal to 11900x95. You should therefore make sure that bot arrays have the correct shape (i.e. `(140, 85, 95)` or `(1130500,)` depending on how you want to calculate your loss).